# comparing two texts in python difflib

Tags: python, text, difflib

A riddle of sorts….I have two text similar text files containing file paths for data that I have downloaded and another for data that I would like to download as part of an automated periodic process. I would however only like to download the new files (the set of 3 that is contained in Text 2 and absent in Text 1). Is there a way to compare and effectively difference two texts using difflib in python yielding a third text containing only the amalgamated difference? Much thanks in advance.
Chase CB

////////Text 1///Old///

/Users/MacBookPro15/1.txt

/Users/MacBookPro15/2.txt

/Users/MacBookPro15/3.txt

////Text 2//////New///

/Users/MacBookPro15/1.txt

/Users/MacBookPro15/2.txt

/Users/MacBookPro15/3.txt

/Users/MacBookPro15/4.txt

/Users/MacBookPro15/5.txt

/Users/MacBookPro15/6.txt

///What I want////Differenced

/Users/MacBookPro15/4.txt

/Users/MacBookPro15/5.txt

/Users/MacBookPro15/6.txt

Comment: What have you tried so far, do you have some code? Also, how large are these files? I think it should be relatively easy to implement something using [`(frozen)set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)s, though I don't know if they scale to monstrous datasets.

Comment: havent tried anything yet never really had to do something like this. i don't think the data set is prohibitively large. many thanks for the response.

Comment: the set stuff worked very nicely. thanks again.